# Controlling which font is used by mathbf

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How do I control which font is used by `\mathbf`?  I have tried here
to make it use Latin Modern (which I think is the default), even
though the main font is something else; but that doesn't happen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ebgaramond}
\newfontfamily\lm{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}
ginger
\[
\lm
\mathbf{f_2^{(3)}}
\]
hawthorn
\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to specify which engine you are using as well. Given that this MWE is using `fontspec` you're either using xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: Also note that this `\lm` function does nothing here. It needs to change the math fonts.

Answer (score 4):

In `fontspec`, `\mathbf` is the bold series of the `\mathrm` font, so you can `\setmathrm[BoldFont = {Some Bold Font}]{some font}`.

The `unicode-math` package works the same way by default, but you can instead give `unicode-math` the `mathbf=sym` option, which then makes `\mathbf` give you the mathematical alphanumeric symbols from your math font.  Normally, you get those symbols with `\symbfup` or `\symbfit`, and they might be more appropriate for single-letter names for vectors and sets. What might be even better is to define semantic markup like `\vectorsym{z}`, which you can change in one place to update the style of all vectors in your document.  You can change the bold upright math alphabet in `unicode-math` with `\setmathfont{Some Font}[range=bfup]`.

In PDFTeX, many font packages change the `\mathrm`, `\mathbf` and `\mathit` alphabets, but one good way to do it is the `isomath` package.  This allows you to pick any NFSS font family, adds several more alphabets such as `\mathbfit`, and also lets you load a font with lowercase Greek letters.

In XeTeX, `mathspec` lets you load a legacy math font with a modern text font, and use the text font’s letters in math mode.

The `mathastext` package makes math mode use letters and numerals from your main text font.  It also has an option to load Greek letters from a LGR-encoded Greek font.

Finally, you can do this manually in LaTeX with `\DeclareMathAlphabet` and `\SetMathAlphabet`.  See [Section 3.4 of the LaTeX Font Selection Guide.](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf#subsection.3.4)